# Error in simultaneous using of newtxtext, txfonts, and mathabx packages

Tags: fonts, mathabx, txfonts

I have a sample code and want to generate a file with Times or New Times Roman font for the text and formulas (hence I used both`newtxtext, txfonts`). Also, I like the symbols shapes that are generated by `mathabx`package. However, it seems in general there would be some inconsistencies. For example, in the output of the following code, if more than three integral symbols are used, `mathabx` does not work properly. Is there any solution for this issue, or I have to sacrifice one thing in favor of the others?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,txfonts,mathabx}


\begin{document}

The text font should be either Times or New Times Roman.
\begin{align*}
x + y + z &= 0 \\
\psi (t) - \Psi (x, t) &= 1
\notag
\end{align*}






  The most important symbols:

  $$ \ast, \cdot, \dagger, \pm, \mp, \div, \star, \times, \approx, \equiv, 
  \doteq $$

  $$ \perp, \mid, \propto, \sim, \simeq, \geq, \gg, \leq, \ll, \neq $$ 

 $$ \int, \oint, \oint\!\oint, \prod, \sum $$

  $$\iint_V \mu(u,v) \,du\,dv $$


  $$\iiiint_V \mu(t,u,v,w) \,dt\,du\,dv\,dw$$

 $$\idotsint_V \mu(u_1,\dots,u_k) \,du_1 \dots du_k$$

 $$ \oint_V f(s) \,ds $$
 $$\idotsint $$





 \end{document}
```

Comment: `mathabx` doesn't have any more than triple integral, i.e. `\iiiint` will be taken from a different font which defines it.

Comment: You shouldn't be loading `newtxtext` and `txfonts` simultaneously. If you need a math font to go with `newtxtext`, load the `newtxmath` package. Or, if you really insist on using `txfonts`, don't load `newtxtext`.